# Does uploading new binary to iTunes Connect lose our place in the review queue?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Our iOS app is "Waiting for Review" on the iOS App Store.

While "waiting for review," do we lose our place in the "waiting for review" queue each time we upload a new binary?

Comment: It's not been clear to me if you preserve your place in line. Why not wait out the review and then submit the update?

Comment: [not an answer] It would be sensible to push any new version to the back of the queue to prevent, 'we got this bit right, hopefully by the time we get to the front of the queue we'll have fixed that bit too' syndrome.

Comment: > Why not wait out the review and then submit the update?  Because then another 8-14 days of time "waiting for review" will elapse until the updates we've completed during the previous "waiting for review" period, can be released.  In contrast, if we could upload on Monday without losing our turn in the review queue for Tuesday, then Monday's work would be included in Tuesday's release.

Comment: > [not an answer] It would be sensible to push any new version to the back of the queue...   I bet that's right.  Otherwise, developers could game the system by submitting junk just to hold a place in the queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Apples Documentation (it puts you in back of the queue):
Removing a Build from Review

Removing a build removes your app version from Apple’s review queue and changes its status to Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your app, the review process starts over from the beginning.

You can remove the build you’ve submitted if its status is any of the following:

Waiting For Export Compliance
Waiting For Review
In Review
Pending Developer Release
Pending Apple Release